# How to show whole datas from table A and table B according to table C?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

**Table A**

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 |
| 2 | A2 |
| 3 | A3 |
| 4 | A4 |
| 5 | A5 |

**Table B**

| id | id_table_A | id_table_C | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Test-1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | Test-2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | Test-3 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | Test-4 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | Test-5 |
| 6 | 5 | 2 | Test-6 |
| 7 | 2 | 2 | Test-7 |

**Table C**

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 |
| 2 | C2 |
| 3 | C3 |

**My Question**
I want to select all datas from table A and also table B, according to id in table C in Laravel (Query Builder or Eloquent doesn't matter). So, it would showing like these:

C1 would showing:

| id_table_A | Name |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | Test-1 |
| A2 | Test-2 |
| A3 | Test-5 |
| A4 | NULL |
| A5 | NULL |

Or when I choose C2, it would showing like:

| id_table_A | Name |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | Test-3 |
| A2 | Test-7 |
| A3 | Test-4 |
| A4 | NULL |
| A5 | Test-6 |

And C3 will showing like:

| id_table_A | Name |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | NULL |
| A2 | NULL |
| A3 | NULL |
| A4 | NULL |
| A5 | NULL |

NB: *Sorry I don't know how to simplify my question*

Comment: You can simplify your question by adding the code you've tried.

Comment: I've tried like
`$data = DB::table('a')->join('b','b.id_table_a','=','a.id')->select('b.*','a.*','c.*')->where('b.id_table_c','=',$id)->get();`

$id I got from Auth session.

Comment: But It can't display all datas in table A.

Comment: Do you have your relation declared between A and C models. if so, mind add the declarations to your question ?

Comment: @N69S No. there's no relation between A and C.

Comment: @beibei declare the relation as described in the answer and you should get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a many to many relation

**A::class**

```
class A extends Model
{
    public function Cs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(C:class, 'b', 'id_table_a', 'id_table_c')->withPivot('id','name');
    }
}
```

Then use this relation to get what you need

```
$as = A::with('Cs')->get();
```

Comment: I got, Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous. Where do I put an alias?

Comment: @beibei  edited the answer. in the where condition just add the table name `c.id`

Comment: It shows, column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'b.name' in 'field list'.  But If I remove it from Pivot, there's nothing datas to show

Comment: in your question you said table b has a field called "name". anyway, if the results are empty, then there is no a entries linked to that c id in `$id`

Comment: Yups, I have asked it (my last question about C3) -- I want to display data from table even there is no a entries linked to that c id in `$id`

Comment: @beibei then remove the whereHas condition, Edited the answer again.

Comment: Sorry, but It still not the result I wanted. if I use this `$as = A::with('Cs')->get();` . Of course it will show all datas from Table A, but didn't answer my question (C1, C2) yet

Comment: @beibei The data is inside the attribute `Cs` on each entry, and inside that you will find the data of `b` inside the attribute `pivot`